# "dotnet watch run" keeps reporting that csproj file has changed when it hasn't changed

Tags: asp.net, .net-core

When I run "dotnet watch run", it keeps reporting that csproj file has changed when it wasn't changed at all. Wonder if anyone can help me resolve this problem.

I am using dotnet version 2.1.401

```
watch : The file watcher observing 'C:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\' encountered an error: Too many changes at once in directory:C:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\.
watch : Exited with error code 1
watch : File changed: C:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\EpdAsset.csproj
watch : Started
watch : The file watcher observing 'C:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\' encountered an error: Too many changes at once in directory:C:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\.
watch : Exited with error code 1
watch : File changed: C:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\EpdAsset.csproj
watch : Started
...............
```

It just keeps exiting and starting. After a long wait, the starting will be successful.

I have logged down some activities happening within the C:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset. Is it normal for so much activities tobe happening within the node_module folder:

Modified (12/9/2018 11:55:00 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\EpdAsset.assets.cache
Modified (12/9/2018 11:55:08 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\EpdAsset.assets.cache
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\package.json
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add.travis.yml
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\binding.gyp
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\fsevents.cc
Modified (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\package.json
Modified (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\install.js
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\install.js
Modified (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add.travis.yml
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\Readme.md
Modified (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\binding.gyp
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build.target.mk
Modified (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\LICENSE
Modified (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\fsevents.js
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\fsevents.js
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\binding.Makefile
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\action_after_build.target.mk
Modified (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md
Modified (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\fsevents.cc
Modified (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build.target.mk
Modified (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\binding.Makefile
Modified (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\Readme.md
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\LICENSE
Modified (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\gyp-mac-tool
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\fse.target.mk
Modified (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\fse.target.mk
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\Makefile
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\gyp-mac-tool
Modified (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\action_after_build.target.mk
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\Release
Modified (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\Makefile
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\Release.deps\Release
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\Release.deps
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\Release.deps\Release\fse.node.d
Modified (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\Release.deps\Release.node.d
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\Release.deps\Release.node.d
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\Release.deps\Release\obj.target
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\Release.deps\Release\obj.target\action_after_build.stamp.d
Modified (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\Release.deps\Release\obj.target\action_after_build.stamp.d
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\Release.deps\Release\obj.target\fse
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\Release.deps\Release\obj.target\fse\fsevents.o.d
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\Release.deps\Users\eshanker\Code
Modified (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\Release.deps\Release\obj.target\fse\fsevents.o.d
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\Release.deps\Users\eshanker\Code\fsevents
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\Release.deps\Users
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\Release.deps\Users\eshanker\Code\fsevents\lib\binding\Release
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\Release.deps\Users\eshanker\Code\fsevents\lib
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\Release.deps\Users\eshanker
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\Release.deps\Users\eshanker\Code\fsevents\lib\binding\Release\node-v64-darwin-x64
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\Release.deps\Users\eshanker\Code\fsevents\lib\binding
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\Release.deps\Users\eshanker\Code\fsevents\lib\binding\Release\node-v64-darwin-x64\fse.node.d
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\Release.node
Modified (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\Release.deps\Users\eshanker\Code\fsevents\lib\binding\Release\node-v64-darwin-x64\fse.node.d
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\Release\obj.target\action_after_build.stamp
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\Release\obj.target
Modified (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\Release.deps\Release\fse.node.d
Modified (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\Release.node
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\Release\fse.node
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\Release\obj.target\fse
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\build\Release\obj.target\fse\fsevents.o
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\lib
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\lib\binding\Release\node-v11-darwin-x64
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\lib\binding
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\lib\binding\Release\node-v11-darwin-x64\fse.node
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\lib\binding\Release
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\lib\binding\Release\node-v46-darwin-x64
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\lib\binding\Release\node-v46-darwin-x64\fse.node
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\lib\binding\Release\node-v47-darwin-x64
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\lib\binding\Release\node-v47-darwin-x64\fse.node
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\lib\binding\Release\node-v48-darwin-x64
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\lib\binding\Release\node-v48-darwin-x64\fse.node
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\lib\binding\Release\node-v57-darwin-x64
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\lib\binding\Release\node-v57-darwin-x64\fse.node
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\lib\binding\Release\node-v64-darwin-x64
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\lib\binding\Release\node-v64-darwin-x64\fse.node
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\src\async.cc
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\src
New (12/9/2018 11:55:15 PM): c:\munlai\websitepractice\EpdAsset\node_modules.staging\fsevents-b9645add\src\locking.cc

................................

Comment: Please specify which "dotnet" version you are using by running `dotnet --version`.

Comment: Can you use Process Monitor from SysInternals to monitor this folder and see what are the changes in "Too many changes at once"? Once that's clear, you might figure out the cause and solution.